# Separate fields in comma delimited fields

Tags: microsoft-access, csv

I am importing a comma delimited file into a ms access database that has statistical information for horse racing.  The file has individual horses, dates of their races, finish position, etc.  I am trying to separate the dates of each horses last 15 races into individual columns rather than seeing all of the dates in one column as it is currently formatted.

Example of current file columns are horse and race date:

```
Mike 3/14/16
Mike 2/14/16
Mike 1/14/16
Mike 12/14/15
Mike 11/14/15
```

CSV file formatted like following:

```
"RCDate","RCRace","Horse", "Finish"
"1/15/16", "1", "Mike", 1"
"1/01/16", "2", "Mike", 2"
"2/15/16", "7", "Mike", 6"
```

I would like each race date to be in a different column such as `racedate1`, `racedate2`, `racedate3`, `racedate4`, `racedate5`, etc.

Comment: Importing where?

Comment: Into a ms access database.

Comment: Please [edit] and include some example data and tell us what program you are importing into.

Comment: If these are separated by a comma (i.e. cell A1 has `10/15/2015;10/16/2016;11/1/2013;10/1/1792`), just use the "Text to Columns", using "Comma" as delimiter.

Comment: @BruceWayne you're talking about an MS Excel feature while OP asks for MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

Open your .csv file with notepad.

At the top, press enter to create a new row.

At the first empty row, enter the following text:

sep=,

Your file would now look something like this:

```
sep=,
Col1, col2, col3
"data 1", data2, "more data"
```

Save the file and try opening it again, and voila, your program suddenly understands that the , is your separator. This works for all MS Office products, might work in others as well. If you have a ; as separator, do `sep=;` obviously.

Comment: Here is some data from the csv file. RCTrack,RCDate,RCRace,Horse,FD,Foreign,Date AQU,3/5/2016,1,Oashaar,D,,1/30/2016   AQU,3/5/2016,1,Ussery's Alley,D,,1/18/2016 AQU,3/5/2016,2,Jonesy Boy,D,,7/11/2015.

Comment: Better layout form the csv file. "RCDate","RCRace","Horse", "Finish"
"1/15/16", "1", "Mike", 1"
"1/01/16", "2", "Mike", 2"
"2/15/16", "7", "Mike", 6"

Comment: @MikeC I don't understand your reasoning to post the actual data on my answer rather than as a comment on your own question. (or better yet, edit your own question). That said, did you try out my answer and did it work for you?

Comment: I am new to the board and posted to wrong place.  I did try your suggestion and it provided the same result by placing all of the data for race date in one column.  In the csv file there is "Date", and that transfer correctly to my database.  My question, and not sure if possible, is there a way to make separate columns for each "Date"?